# Unity - Circle Collider 2D traveling the side of a wall randomly collides with wall corner

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, tiled2unity

I have a 2D golf game that uses a Circle Collider 2D on the ball, and I have levels/holes built out in Tiled, which I import into Unity using SuperTiled2Unity. Being a somewhat retro styled pixel art-y game, there are a lot of straight edges and corners, especially on walls. If my ball is colliding with the wall, and I shoot perfectly straight upward, I would expect the ball *not* to collide with the corner of the wall as it falls back down. Instead, it will collide with the corner of the wall totally at random. See the .gif I created of the issue below - I take a total of 4 shots in this gif. They are at the same angle (perfectly straight up), and it doesn't collide with the wall corner until the 4th shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL6B4.jpg

I know for a fact that I am shooting perfectly straight up, and there are no other forces at play here other than gravity - which should pull the ball perfectly straight back down. Here's an image of how the colliders look in the scene view:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf0J4.jpg

What could be causing this? I tried setting up a similar scenario with an Edge collider for a wall instead of the Polygon Collider that SuperTiled2Unity generates, but the same issues happened.

I looked around for quite some time to see if I could find anyone with a similar issue, but didn't see anything. Unfortunately it's somewhat of a hard issue to describe, and therefore hard to search for.

Any suggestions or ideas for how to fix or workaround this would be very appreciated. I feel like I've tweaked and messed with every single possibly relevant 2d physics setting within unity.

(I also posted this over on the Unity physics forums - nobody replied. I've also posted it on the Unity2D reddit, and didn't get very far with it there.)

Comment: A quick guess: Is the `Collision Detection` set to `Continuous Speculative`?  Collision may be inaccurate at high speed. See [ContinuousCollisionDetection](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ContinuousCollisionDetection.html).

Comment: @Mangata, I think those are specific to unity's 3D physics. Here's how I have the rigidbody set up: https://imgur.com/a/P9miHou

"Discrete" is the only other option.
It's also worth noting that the rigidbody isnt moving very fast at all.